# Byte addressable memory and ISA

Tags: memory, cpu, register, isa

I am trying to clear some confusion regarding instruction set architecture and how memory is accessed.  Basically I know that in byte addressable memory, data is stored byte by byte either in big-endian or little-endian.  Now if we have a 32 bit processor, meaning that we could use 32 bit registers; do data buses transfer 4 bytes of data at a time at each clock cycle?  Also, are the instructions also 32 bits long? How does that affect the opcode size versus the operand size?

Comment: Quick pseudo-answer: instruction size is independent of data register size; data buses to main memory are often wider and typically used to fill a cache block at a time (over multiple "beats" [twice bus cycle for DDR]), the connection between L1 cache and the core may be *wider* than the core's general purpose registers to support load pair/multiple operations or single access FP/SIMD register load/store (when such are larger than the GPRs) and two banks may be accessed simultaneously to support unaligned accesses. (Icache may also provide more than 1 instruction per cycle.)

Comment: This question is too broad because the answers could vary significantly depending on the ISA.

Answer (score 0):

> do data buses transfer 4 bytes of data at a time at each clock cycle?

This is entirely up to the system design, but I'm gonna say yes, they transfer 4 bytes of data at each clock cycle (if they are instructed to, ofcourse) **assuming** that you are a computer engineering/science student taking a computer organization/architecture class. However, this might not always be the case as contemporary computer architectures are far more sophisticated than what you see in your computer organization/architecture course.

I recommend you to read [Everything you need to know about DDR, DDR2 and DDR3 memories](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Everything-You-Need-To-Know-About-DDR-DDR2-and-DDR3-Memories/167) so that you can have an idea how double data rate transfers occur.

> Also, are the instructions also 32 bits long?

Not necessarily. It's up to the design system. I recommend you read about [RISC and CISC architectures](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/risc/risccisc/).

[[Source](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1101/1101.5364.pdf)]
For example, A Complex Instruction Set Computer (CISC) with IA-32 (namely Intel i386 architecture) might have instructions of length 1 byte to 12 bytes (8 bits to 96 bits) while it has 32-bit data registers.

> How does that affect the opcode size versus the operand size?

Again, completely up to the design decisions.